# Why can´t I save int with shared_preferences?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to build a simple application, which shoul save and output a `value` whith `shared_preferences`. I tried to save an `int`, but it doesnt´t work. It could be, that the mistake is because of I tried to "convert" the code a youtuber did with a `String` instead of an `int`. Can anybody find my mistake? Below is the change code I tried.

```
 int lastLoginInt = 1;
 String nameKey = "_key_name";
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<bool> saveLastLoginInt() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return await preferences.setInt(nameKey, lastLoginInt);
  }

  Future<int> loadLastLoginInt() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences.getInt(nameKey);
  }

  setLastLoginInt() {
    loadLastLoginInt().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        lastLoginInt = value;
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: I don't see any call to `saveLastLoginInt()`

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling functions.

Probably you should do this at your `initState()` function..like this..

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    saveLastLoginInt();
  }
```

Then use `setLastLoginInt()` where needed.